# Tryng to use sys in pycharam

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I am trying to grab the 1st and 2nd argument using sys but i am unable to do so this is the code i am using :

```
import sys
import os
from PIL import  Image
image_folder=sys.argv[1]
image_folder2=sys.argv[2]
print(image_folder)
```

***this is the error***

> File "C:/Users/hp/PycharmProjects/test sys/test.py", line 4, in 
>    image_folder=sys.argv[1]
>    IndexError: list index out of range

Any kind of help is appreciate[enter image description here][2]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the command line arguments from the run configuration.

Comment: thank for your help